# What is the relation between ContentPane and JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I found one example in which buttons are added to panels (instances of `JPanel`) then panels are added to the the containers (instances generated by `getContentPane()`) and then containers are, by the construction, included into the `JFrame` (the windows).

I tried two things:

1. I got rid of the containers. In more details, I added buttons to a panel (instance of `JPanel`) and then I added the panel to the windows (instance of `JFrame`). It worked fine.
2. I got rid of the panels. In more details, I added buttons directly to the container and then I added the container to the window (instance of `JFrame`).

So, I do not understand two things.

1. Why do we have two competing mechanism to do the same things?
2. What is the reason to use containers in combination with the panels (`JPanel`)? (For example, what for we include buttons in JPanels and then we include JPanels in the Containers). Can we include `JPanel` in `JPanel`? Can we include a container in container?

**ADDED:**

Maybe essence of my question can be put into one line of code:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
```

What for we put `getContentPane()` in between? I tried just `frame.add(panel);` and it works fine.

**ADDED 2:**

I would like to add some code to be more clear about what I mean. In this example I use only JPane:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class HelloWorldSwing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());        
        panel.add(new JButton("W"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(new JButton("E"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And in this example I use only Content Pane:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class HelloWorldSwing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing");
    Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
    pane.add(new JButton("W"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    pane.add(new JButton("E"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Both work fine! I just want to know if between these two ways to do things one is better (safer).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's not two competing mechanisms - a `JPanel` ***is a*** `Container` (just look at the class hierarchy at the top of the [JPanel javadocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html)).  `JFrame.getContentPane()` just returns a `Container` to place the `Component`s that you want to display in the `JFrame`.  Internally, it's using a `JPanel` (by default - you can change this by calling `setContentPane()`)  As for why it's returning a `Container` instead of a `JPanel` - it's because you should [program to an interface, not an implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) - at that level, all that you need to care about is that you can add `Component`s to something - and even though `Container` is a class rather than an interface - it provides the interface needed to do exactly that.

As for why both `JFrame.add()` and `JFrame.getContentPane().add()` both do the same thing - `JFrame.add()` is overridden to call `JFrame.getContentPane().add()`. This wasn't always the case - pre-JDK 1.5 you always had to specify `JFrame.getContentPane().add()` explicitly and `JFrame.add()` threw a `RuntimeException` if you called it, but due to many complaints, this was changed in JDK 1.5 to do what you'd expect.

Comment: @Nate, what do you mean by " Internally, it's using a JPanel". You mean that Container is using a JPanel? What do you mean by that? I though that JPanel is a subclass of Container. And what can I change by "setContentPane"? OK. You say that Container is a class (and I always considered Container as a class). But JPane is also a class. Why we cannot use just JPane or just Container? I was able to do the same things by using only JPane. I was also able to do the same using only Containers.

Comment: `JFrame` is internally using a `JPanel` object to back the `getContentPane()` method. This is why Zachary's answer works.  The actual `JPanel` reference is buried in the `JFrame.rootPane` field.  You would call `setContentPane()` on the `JFrame` - for example, you could change line 10 in your first example from `frame.add(panel)` to `frame.setContentPane(panel)`.  `Container` is a class.  `JPanel` is a class (which is a subclass of `Container`).  You're confusing the type of the reference with the type of the object the reference references.  Think about `Container container = new JPanel()`

Comment: @Nate the source (http://pragmaticjava.blogspot.com.ar/2008/08/program-to-interface-not-implementation.html) has been removed.

Comment: @Lucio Thanks! Changed the link to a question here on StackOverflow about the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Good question. I found it helpful to understand that "Swing provides three generally useful top-level container classes: `JFrame`, `JDialog`, and `JApplet`. ... As a convenience, the add method and its variants, remove and setLayout have been overridden to forward to the contentPane as necessary."—[*Using Top-Level Containers*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason is because Swing was built off of AWT, and Container is a top level AWT object. It really isn't the greatest design choice, though, since you generally don't want to mix AWT (heavyweight) objects with Swing (lightweight).

I think the best way to handle it is to always cast the contentPane to a JPanel.

```
JPanel contentPanel = (JPanel)aFrame.getContentPane();
```

Comment: It's not mixing AWT and Swing components... see my answer

Answer (score 1):

It is all written in the last version [API doc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) that JFrame.add() (nowerdays) is enough.

You may compare to older Java versions [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html).

Answer (score 1):

interesting: `jframe.setBackground(color)` does not work for me, but `jframe.getContentPane().setBackground(color)` works.

Answer (score 1):

The history and mechanics of this are also discussed in some detail at [this leepoint article](http://leepoint.net/JavaBasics/gui/gui-commentary/guicom-60-contentpane.html). Note in particular:

> `getContentPane()` returns a `Container` object. This isn't really a plain `Container` object, but is actually a `JPanel`! This is a `Container` as a consequence of the hierarchy. So if we get the predefined content pane, it turns out it's actually a `JPanel`, but we really can't take advantage of the functionality that was added by `JComponent`.

and

> They defined `add()` methods in `JFrame` which simply call the corresponding `add()` methods for the content pane. It seems strange to add this feature now, especially since many layouts use multiple nested panels so you still have to be comfortable with adding directly to a `JPanel`. And not everything you want to do with the content pane can be done through calls to the `JFrame`.