# Visualize JUNG example in existing frame

Tags: java, user-interface, jung

I am trying to use one of the [JUNG visualisation](http://jung.sourceforge.net/index.html) examples in the project that I am working on.

The examplecode (provided by JUNG) that I want to use looks like this:

```
package TreeVisualiser;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;

import org.apache.commons.collections15.Factory;
import org.apache.commons.collections15.functors.ConstantTransformer;

import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.PolarPoint;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.RadialTreeLayout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.TreeLayout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.DirectedGraph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.DirectedSparseMultigraph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Forest;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.DelegateForest;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.DelegateTree;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Tree;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.GraphZoomScrollPane;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.Layer;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.VisualizationServer;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.VisualizationViewer;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.control.CrossoverScalingControl;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.control.DefaultModalGraphMouse;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.control.ModalGraphMouse;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.control.ScalingControl;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.decorators.EdgeShape;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.decorators.ToStringLabeller;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.layout.LayoutTransition;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.util.Animator;

/**
 * Demonsrates TreeLayout and RadialTreeLayout.
 * @author Tom Nelson
 * 
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TreeVisualiser extends JApplet {

    Forest<String,Integer>                 graph;

    Factory<DirectedGraph<String,Integer>> graphFactory =  new Factory<DirectedGraph<String,Integer>>() { 
                                                                public DirectedGraph<String, Integer> create() {
                                                                    return new DirectedSparseMultigraph<String,Integer>();
                                                                }
                                                            };

    Factory<Tree<String,Integer>>          treeFactory = new Factory<Tree<String,Integer>> () {
                                                                public Tree<String, Integer> create() {
                                                                    return new DelegateTree<String,Integer>(graphFactory);
                                                                }
                                                         };

    Factory<Integer>                        edgeFactory = new Factory<Integer>() {
                                                            int i=0;
                                                            public Integer create() {
                                                                    return i++;
                                                            }
                                                           };

    Factory<String>                         vertexFactory = new Factory<String>() {
                                                                int i=0;
                                                                public String create() {
                                                                    return "V"+i++;
                                                                }
                                                            };
/**
 * the visual component and renderer for the graph
 */
VisualizationViewer<String,Integer>     vv;

VisualizationServer.Paintable           rings;

String                                  root;

TreeLayout<String,Integer>              treeLayout;

RadialTreeLayout<String,Integer>        radialLayout;



@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
public TreeVisualiser() {

    // create a simple graph for the demo
    graph = new DelegateForest<String,Integer>();

    createTree();

    treeLayout = new TreeLayout<String,Integer>(graph);
    radialLayout = new RadialTreeLayout<String,Integer>(graph);
    radialLayout.setSize(new Dimension(600,600));
    vv =  new VisualizationViewer<String,Integer>(treeLayout, new Dimension(600,600));
    vv.setBackground(Color.white);
    vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeShapeTransformer(new EdgeShape.Line());
    vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller());
    // add a listener for ToolTips
    vv.setVertexToolTipTransformer(new ToStringLabeller());
    vv.getRenderContext().setArrowFillPaintTransformer(new ConstantTransformer(Color.lightGray));
    rings = new Rings();

    Container content = getContentPane();
    final GraphZoomScrollPane panel = new GraphZoomScrollPane(vv);
    content.add(panel);

    final DefaultModalGraphMouse graphMouse = new DefaultModalGraphMouse();

    vv.setGraphMouse(graphMouse);

    JComboBox modeBox = graphMouse.getModeComboBox();
    modeBox.addItemListener(graphMouse.getModeListener());
    graphMouse.setMode(ModalGraphMouse.Mode.TRANSFORMING);

    final ScalingControl scaler = new CrossoverScalingControl();

    JButton plus = new JButton("+");
    plus.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            scaler.scale(vv, 1.1f, vv.getCenter());
        }
    });
    JButton minus = new JButton("-");
    minus.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            scaler.scale(vv, 1/1.1f, vv.getCenter());
        }
    });

    JToggleButton radial = new JToggleButton("Radial");
    radial.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {

                LayoutTransition<String,Integer> lt =
                    new LayoutTransition<String,Integer>(vv, treeLayout, radialLayout);
                Animator animator = new Animator(lt);
                animator.start();
                vv.getRenderContext().getMultiLayerTransformer().setToIdentity();
                vv.addPreRenderPaintable(rings);
            } else {
                LayoutTransition<String,Integer> lt =
                    new LayoutTransition<String,Integer>(vv, radialLayout, treeLayout);
                Animator animator = new Animator(lt);
                animator.start();
                vv.getRenderContext().getMultiLayerTransformer().setToIdentity();
                vv.removePreRenderPaintable(rings);
            }
            vv.repaint();
        }});

    JPanel scaleGrid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0));
    scaleGrid.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Zoom"));

    JPanel controls = new JPanel();
    scaleGrid.add(plus);
    scaleGrid.add(minus);
    controls.add(radial);
    controls.add(scaleGrid);
    controls.add(modeBox);

    content.add(controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

class Rings implements VisualizationServer.Paintable {

    Collection<Double> depths;

    public Rings() {
        depths = getDepths();
    }

    private Collection<Double> getDepths() {
        Set<Double> depths = new HashSet<Double>();
        Map<String,PolarPoint> polarLocations = radialLayout.getPolarLocations();
        for(String v : graph.getVertices()) {
            PolarPoint pp = polarLocations.get(v);
            depths.add(pp.getRadius());
        }
        return depths;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.lightGray);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        Point2D center = radialLayout.getCenter();

        Ellipse2D ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double();
        for(double d : depths) {
            ellipse.setFrameFromDiagonal(center.getX()-d, center.getY()-d, 
                    center.getX()+d, center.getY()+d);
            Shape shape = vv.getRenderContext().getMultiLayerTransformer().getTransformer(Layer.LAYOUT).transform(ellipse);
            g2d.draw(shape);
        }
    }

    public boolean useTransform() {
        return true;
    }
}

/**
 * 
 */
private void createTree() {
    graph.addVertex("V0");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), "V0", "V1");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), "V0", "V2");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), "V1", "V4");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), "V2", "V3");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), "V2", "V5");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), "V4", "V6");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), "V4", "V7");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), "V3", "V8");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), "V6", "V9");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), "V4", "V10");

    graph.addVertex("A0");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), "A0", "A1");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), "A0", "A2");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), "A0", "A3");

    graph.addVertex("B0");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), "B0", "B1");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), "B0", "B2");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), "B1", "B4");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), "B2", "B3");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), "B2", "B5");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), "B4", "B6");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), "B4", "B7");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), "B3", "B8");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), "B6", "B9");

}


/**
 * a driver for this demo
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Container content = frame.getContentPane();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    content.add(new TreeVisualiser());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

In the example the graph is constructed directly in an frame, but I would like use the graph in a GUI that I already build. For this, the same graph has to be put in a panel:

```
public MainGUI(String s) {
     super(s);

     // Content pane
     Container content = this.getContentPane();
     content.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
     content.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
     GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

 treePanel = new JPanel();
     c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
     c.ipadx = FRAMEX - 25;
     c.ipady = FRAMEY - 300;      //make this component tall
     c.gridwidth = 3;
     c.gridx = 0;
     c.gridy = 1;
     content.add(treePanel, c);
     }

private void displayTree() {
     treePanel.add(new TreeVisualiser());
 }
```

This doesn't show the graph at all. Has anyone experience with the use of the JUNG library and knows what the problem could be here?

Comment: Are you sure you are painting the graph in the visible region? If I remember correctly JUNG and awt/swing are using different coordinate systems. For JUNG (0,0) is the lower left corner, but for awt this is the upper left.

Comment: The example of JUNG also uses a JFrame from swing, so I thought that this couldn't be the problem?

Comment: Does your graph correctly render in your non-custom GUI?  Also, can you get other things to render in that pane in your custom GUI?

Comment: The graph correctly renders in the non-custom GUI.
I tried to add a new button to the panel of my custom GUI but that didn't work out, so there should be a problem with the pane itself.

Comment: What is `this` in `this.getContentPane();` line? A Swing Frame? A Swing Panel? Later you used `content (Container)` to add `treePanel (Panel)`. Then, in `treePanel`, you added Jung object of `TreeVisualiser`. This is different from Jung sample: Frame -> Container -> TreeVisualiser. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432839/what-is-the-relation-between-contentpane-and-jpanel

Comment: Check this. For JUNG it is simmiliar.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279435/java-how-would-i-dynamically-add-swing-component-to-gui-on-click