# How to customize JTextField?

Tags: java, jtextfield, setbackground

I have a **java** Desktop application. For new module I designed a class which extends the **JTextFields**. I added four **JTextFields** in that class. I want to change the **background** color of these **JTextFields**, I used **setBackground** method. But the background color is not changed, JVM inherits the background color from my main application. How I will **customize** my new **JTextFields**? Please suggest a good solution.

Comment: There is a similar question. Have a look at [this][1]. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106936/java-changing-a-jlabel-with-texts-stored-in-an-array/23107479#23107479

Comment: @VishwaDany, kindly share your relevant code for better help

Comment: Remember to add `component.setOpaque(true)`

Comment: Why are you extending JTextField just to change the background color. There is no need to do this. Just invoke the setBackground(...) method on the text field. Please suggest a good solution. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. There is now way we can help based on the information in your question